# can't include the .php file properly

Tags: php

I am trying to include different php files in the `index.php` file

on my webpage

http://www.e-lang.de/index.php

but the contents are included as simple text. What I want is that they should be proper DOM elements not the text.

here is my `index.php`

```
 <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar mt10">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a href="#" class="brand">اردو ایڈیٹر</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">صفحۂ اول</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page=start">رابطہ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php include_once "editor.php"; ?>

        <!-- hidden inline form -->
        <?php include_once "emailform.html"; ?>

    </div>
```

and editor.php looks like

```
<div class="well widget">
    <div class="widget-header">
        <h3 class="title">اُردوھے جس کا نام</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span7">
            <form method="post" action="save.php" id="text-container">
                <input type="hidden" name="save" value="0" id="savetext">
                <textarea rows="22"  id="text-urdu" name="text" class="span7" dir="rtl"  style="font: normal 25px Arial"></textarea>
            </form>
            <div class="rel">
                <div id="counter"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="help-wrapper">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span11">
            <div class="well widget" id="buttons-listing">
                <ul class="listing">
                    <li><a href="#" class="button" onclick="print()">Print</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="button" onclick="save()">Save</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="button" onclick="pdf()">pdf</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="tweet()" ><img src="webroot/img/tweet.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="button"  id="btn_email" >E-Mail</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Can you please include your php scripts here?

Comment: it seems that you did't have a correct php-tag, its shown as <�?php, so it would not be parsed by php

Comment: What does your include file contain?

Comment: looks like that file is suffering from a encoding issue.

Comment: make sure both index.php file and the include file has the same encoding.

Comment: Please post the lines of code where you perform the include and the entire contents of the included files. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no actual PHP in editor.php. Please remove the first line (containing the PHP open tag, `<?php`) from the editor.php file, as that should only surround PHP code. For standard HTML, you don't need to use the `<?php` tag.

Comment: Yep... makes my answer look like I'm making stuff up.  And of course, the end result looks perfectly fine on the sample page.  The issue went away.